# How to boot to Ubuntu live USB from Ubuntu desktop? (b/c splash logo, BIOS, and Windows OS all crashed on me)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, uefi

I have a desktop that had Win10 and Ubuntu20.04 dual booted on it, everything was happy for a while, then the splash logo, ability to go to boot settings or BIOS, or boot into Windows all went away. During the time period that these options should display, be available, or respond to the F11 key (that's what it is on mine), it is just black (no HDMI output). Then the Ubuntu logo shows up and Ubuntu OS loads. I don't know what triggered this.

So at least I have one working OS. Not bad.

But I'd like to boot from live USB to repair Windows / reinstall Grub ala [this help tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix). But it requires booting into the live USB.

Is there a way to boot into Ubuntu 20.04 live USB from Ubuntu 20.04 desktop? Seems like there should be, Ubuntu / linux are very versatile. Maybe I just haven't scoured to the ends of the internet quite enough yet.

Help/advice appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Just plugging in the USB to the BIOS Flash USB socket on my desktop doesn't work, either. I tried a few but not all of the sockets.

Comment: I suggest that you consult the documentation for your motherboard. Nothing you do in any operating system is going to prevent you from accessing your motherboard firmware (BIOS) or using your motherboard firmware to boot a valid bootable volume. This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) because the answer to your question is "Yes, you can run another instance of Ubuntu while Ubuntu is running using a VM" -- but now that you have that answer, it still doesn't solve your actual problem- which is that you need to figure out how to operate your particular hardware.

Comment: Did Windows update UEFI or UEFI settings?. Default then may be to prevent USB boot and you need to redo the UEFI settings you originally did. Often a full "cold" boot or from total power down may work. And Windows may have turned fast startup/hibernation back on. Grub only boots working Windows which also means no fast startup/hibernation. Download manual for your system as it typically offers more explanation of UEFI settings than the UEFI screen.

Comment: Thank you, @Nmath, you're right. I often have XY problems for some reason.

Comment: I solved the problem. It was a hardware issue. The BIOS cable was loose b/c the graphics card is big.